# How to use a variable as object in a class in python

Tags: python, json, class

I am attempting to find the number of unique customers for each worker from a .json file. `transactions["transactions"][a]["worker]` will return either Ben or David, these are the only workers and have previously been defined as objects within a class called Workers. In the for loop, I want the worker's name to be assigned to the variable wrkr, and the customer's name assigned the variable cust. I then want to check if the customer is already in that worker's list of customers, if it isn't, then I will append the name of the customer to the list. If they are already in the list I want the loop to iterate to the next transaction.

Ben.customers gives the list of customers (initially none) but if I set the variable wrkr = Ben and then do wrkr.customers it doesn't it gives me the error "AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'customers'". I can see why as it just sees wrkr as a name and looks for it within the class. But I don't know what I should do instead?

```
import json

with open("transactions.json", "r") as f:
    transactions = json.load(f)

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, name, customers):
        self.name = name
        self.customers = customers

David = Worker("David", [])
Ben = Worker("Ben", [])

# Find the number of unique customers for each worker
for a in range(len(transactions["transactions"])):
    cust = transactions["transactions"][a]["customer"]
    wrkr = transactions["transactions"][a]["worker"]
    if cust in wrkr.customers:
        continue
    else:
        wrkr.customers.append(cust)
```

Gives me the error "AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'customers'"

I want to find a workers name within the for loop and then load that worker's customer list.

I'm really sorry if my question doesn't make much sense or I'm using the wrong terminology. I'm self taught and don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: The error you received was from the fact that `wrkr` is a unicode string, that means `wrkr.customers` will give that error.

Comment: Python 3, is there a way to fix this very simply just by making a variable that is a part of the workers class?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a dictionary with the keys being the worker names being expected in the json and the value being the Worker objects

```
class Worker:
    def __init__(self, name, customers=None):
        self.name = name
        # If you want an empty list as a default parameter you can follow this pattern
        self.customers = customers or []

workers = {
    'David': Worker("David"),
    'Ben': Worker("Ben")
}

for transaction_details in transactions["transactions"].values():
    cust = transaction_details["customer"]
    # Here you can get the Worker object from the dictionary using the worker name
    wrkr = workers.get(transaction_details["worker"])
    # You should handle the case where the worker is not expected
    if cust in wrkr.customers:
        continue
    else:
        wrkr.customers.append(cust)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I am trying to guess what your data looks like, which is not easy, so if my solution does not work, please post what your data looks like. Here is what I have in mind:

```
import itertools
import json
from pprint import pprint

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, name, customers):
        self.name = name
        self.customers = customers

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Worker(name={}, customers={})'.format(self.name,
                                                      self.customers)


with open('transactions.json') as file_handle:
    data = json.load(file_handle)

#workers is a dictionary where key=worker name, value=Worker object
workers = {}

for transaction in data['transactions']:
    worker_name = transaction['worker']
    customer = transaction['customer']

    #Create a new worker object if needed
    workers.setdefault(worker_name, Worker(worker_name, set()))

    #Build the customers list
    workers[worker_name].customers.add(customer)

pprint(workers)
```

Output:

```
{'Ben': Worker(name=Ben, customers={'Lisa', 'Janet', 'Alex'}),
 'David': Worker(name=David, customers={'Jason', 'Anna'})}
```

Notes

- Instead of having two variables `Ben` and `David`, I created a dictionary named `workers` for easy look up. The keys are the name of the workers and the values the `Worker` objects.
- From your code, you have a test to make sure not to add the same name to the customers list. This tells me that you want a set, not a list. Using a set with simplify your logic because you don't have to deal with `if/else` statement.
- The `workers.setdefault()` call deserve some explanation if you are not familiar with it. Here is what the documentation said:

  ```
  setdefault(key[, default])
  ```

  > If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with a value of default and return default. default defaults to None.

  What this means is let say that the key 'Ben' is not in the dictionary, the `setdefault` method will add a new key/value to the dictionary. If the key is already in the dictionary, the `setdefault` does not do anything, but return the current value. Thus the line:

  ```
  workers.setdefault(worker_name, Worker(worker_name, set()))
  ```

  is equivalent to:

  ```
  if worker_name not in workers:
      workers[worker_name] = Worker(worker_name, set())
  ```

Comment: I am confused of the usage of "set( )" in Worker(worker_name, set( ) )

Comment: I have figured out the usage of set( ) it just creates a worker with an empty set of customers if they didn't exist already, now I am confused on the __repr__ function you defined, what does it do?